# Applying Choices in Fields using View in Lotus Domino Web application

Tags: javascript, lotus, lotus-domino

I can't quite figure out a work around for using "Use view dialog for choices" in a web based application.

My Question is how can i convert this settings in my field in the Control Tab then Choices, in choices "Use view dialog for choices" then Use current database and access view and a specific column.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

"Use view dialog for choices" is almost always a way to get around the restrictions on the return value of a formula. For instance, you'd use it when @DbColumn in a choices formula for a listbox or dialog list choices formula would cause an error.

The upshot of that is that there's no "one-shot" workaround for the web. A direct functional replacement would be to open the view in a pop-up window or overlay div, and attach some JavaScript to the view in order to override the default web behaviour and force the return of values to a field on the main document. This approach will work well, but it may require server settings that allow the entire view to be served at once (the maximum lines to display per page will probably be less than you need), and it's subject to breakage if the HTML used to display the view ever changes.

You can use LotusScript or Java in a WebQueryOpen agent to populate a conventional widget (the  list of a  element) in a Rich Text field, either using PassThru HTML or a "Treat contents as HTML" form. That would involve getting the view, then doing a document-by-document (or category-by-category) run through the view index to get the column values you need. (If you take this approach, use the ColumnValues rather than the document field name to retrieve the values -- the cost of opening the document to read the values is high, and your code will take many times longer to run.)

You can also get the view as need using an AJAX request and a ?ReadViewEntries query, which will return an XML representation of the view. Again, you may have to have the maximum view lines per page limit upped in order to get the amount of data you need. You can get around that, though, by using a "suggest" method that doesn't begin retrieving data until the user enters at least one character into the field.

All of these approaches mean using a separate form for the web. That's easy enough -- you simply create a form with the same alias (or name, if you're not using aliases) as the one you're using for the Notes client. In the list of forms in Designer, you can use the hidewhen tab to hide one from the Notes client and the other from the web. (Note that you can create an additional form for mobile devices the same way if necessary.)

I can't get more specific than this with the information at hand. If this is insufficient to point you in the right direction, then edit your question to be more specific (and post a comment to this reply -- I don't spend a lot of time on SO, but I do spend time on other StackExchange sites, so I'll be notified).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have to develop it yourself.

http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=AJAX%20Name%20Picker

AJAX-based name picker is a good start I guess.